# Find which method WCF will dispatch a RESTful request to

Tags: wcf, wcf-rest, method-dispatch

Suppose I implement a WCF [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) service with the following contract.

```cs
[ServiceContract]
interface INotesService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "notes/{id}")]
    Note GetNote(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "notes")]
    IEnumerable<Note> GetNotes();
}
```

Now, I have an HttpModule in the pipeline to do the authorization, but that code needs to know to which method the request will be dispatched. How do I find the signature of the method that will be invoked by WCF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the other answer put me on the right path, it did not really answer my question.

I later found this link which gave me a working solution:
http://tech.blog.oceg.org/2009/04/authorizing-rest-calls-in-wcf.html

However, I found it to be more complex than needed. In .NET 4.5 (which is what I'm on) you can do the following.

I registered my ServiceAuthorizationManager from the ServiceHost.ApplyConfiguration override.

```
this.Authorization.ServiceAuthorizationManager = 
       new MyServiceAuthorizationManager();
```

Then, in its CheckAccessCore method, I called the method below to give me the name of the method to which the request will be dispatched.

```
private string GetOperationName(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    return messageProperties["HttpOperationName"] as string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [IDispatchOperationSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchoperationselector.aspx).

See also this article: [WCF Extensibility – Operation Selectors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/05/10/wcf-extensibility-operation-selectors.aspx)

Comment: This looks very promising, thanks! I'll try it out and mark this answer as accepted if it works for me.